# Can i migrate existing vpc to new account using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to migrate my existing VPC, subnets etc from one amazon account to another amazon account using cloud formation.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you have a CloudFormation template for your VPC already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a CloudFormation template for your VPC environment already, then you can simply create a new stack using that same template in another AWS account.

However, this will create a copy of your VPC environment as it was when it was initially created. Any changes done to the VPC since it was created using CloudFormation will not be included. This will include the acquisition of data in a database, for example.

If you do not already have a CloudFormation template, you can try to create one using AWS Cloud Former. Cloud Former can be used to examine your AWS environment and create a CloudFormation template from what it sees.

Instructions for running AWS Cloud Former can be found in the AWS Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: In my case i have not created yet any template from existing account but thanks for sharing this will help a lot.